# What is $\operatorname{Hom}_A (e_i A, e_j A)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field. Assume that $A$ is a finite dimensional $K$-algebra with a complete set $\left\{e_{1}, \ldots, e_{n}\right\}$ of primitive orthogonal idempotents. What is $\operatorname{Hom}_A (e_i A, e_j A)$? And what is the relation between $\operatorname{Hom}_A (e_i A, e_j A)$ and $0$?

Thank you!

Comment: seems like the collection of morphisms between the projection of $A$ onto the image of $e_i$ and $e_j $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be a ring and let $e,f\in A$ be idempotents; suppose $\varphi\colon eA\to fA$ be a morphism of right $A$-modules. Then
$$
\varphi(e)=\varphi(ee)=\varphi(e)e
$$
If $c=\varphi(e)$, then you need that $ce=c$, that is, $c\in Ae$. On the other hand, $c\in fA$, so you conclude that $c\in fAe$.

Once you know $c$, you have, for every $a\in A$,
$$
\varphi(ea)=ca
$$
Conversely, fix $c\in fAe$, which means that $fc=c$ and $ce=c$. Then we can define $f(ea)=ca\in fA$. If $ea=eb$, then $e(a-b)=0$ and
$$
c(a-b)=ce(a-b)=0
$$
so the map $ea\mapsto ca$ is well defined and it is obviously a morphism of right $A$-modules.

Can $c,c'\in fAe$ define the same morphism? If they do, then $ce=c'e$, but this implies $c=c'$.

Thus, as abelian groups, $\operatorname{Hom}_A(eA,fA)\cong fAe$.